# Why does allocation of std::aligned_storage always have an offset?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-alignment

When allocating an `std::aligned_storage<2, 4096>::type` on the heap I always get a pointer that is offset by 16 bytes (on x64; on x86 it is offset by 8 bytes). In other words, this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int main() {
    typedef std::aligned_storage<2, 4096>::type MemPage;

    MemPage* p_mp = new MemPage;

    std::cout << (void*)p_mp << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives me (for example)

```
0x72f010
```

although I would expect all the last three digits to be zero. When allocating the `std::aligned_storage<>::type` on the stack everything works as expected.

I use gcc-4.8.2 x86_64 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @TobiasBrüll No, everything's fine. I must have misread the code, pardon.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Offset from 4K page boundaries.

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: Doesn't the allocator reserve the right to add some metadata before your dynamically-allocated object?

Comment: hmm apparently only for array types

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you mean by "only for array types"?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: Exactly what I said. `new` is allowed to pad its allocated memory but only if you're `new`ing an object of array type. `std::aligned_storage<>` instantiations are not array types though, in common implementations, their sole member _is_ an array type and that member holds the `alignas` constraint. I wonder whether that's in play here.

Comment: Does it always end in `010`?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, always 16 bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not quite clear how the alignment requirements transpose to storage allocated with `new`. The standard maintains in [expr.new] that

> It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported
>   (3.11).

[basic.align]/3:

> An *extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than
>   `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. It is implementation-defined whether any
>   extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are
>   supported (7.6.2). **A type having an extended alignment requirement
>   is an *over-aligned type***.

Over-aligned types might not be supported by GCC, and the "non-support" of this might (instead of a compiler error) lead to the allocation function only returning storage aligned with the *strictest fundamental alignment*: `sizeof(std::max_align_t)`. If the value of the latter is 16 on your machine, that would explain that the address is a multiple of 16.

Also note that, despite the fact that runtime allocation functions will have maximum supported alignments, `operator new` can basically not take desired alignments into account as it has no parameter that could take the corresponding value and pass it on to the runtime environments allocation function. This problem is known and subject of an [EWG-issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3396.htm).

---

Fun-fact: The above code is invoking UB. Consider the table in [meta.trans.ptr] that lists the requirements for `aligned_storage`s second template argument:

> `Align` shall be equal to `alignof(T)` for some type `T` or to
>   *default-alignment*.

If no type `T` has an alignment of `4096` the requirement for the template argument is not fit. And what type would have an alignment of *2<sup>12</sup>*?

However, this is not important to the essence of the question. We can just use `new` with an own typedef.

Comment: Not arguing with your answer: But on the stack it works reliably. Do you think I should try to submit a bug to gcc?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll Stack allocations are handled by the compiler, heap allocations are (largely) handled by the run-time. Whatever maximal alighment the run-time is configured to support, you could come up with a bigger number that the run-time does not support. I'm pretty sure I've seen a bug report about it once already and that the GCC developers don't consider it a serious enough problem to actively handle (a point of view to which I'm somewhat sympathetic).

Comment: @hvd Note that if an array of `MemPage` is allocated, then the objects are separated by 4K. So there has to be some kind of information flow about alignment to the run-time.

Comment: Ah, found [the bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36159). `::operator new(size_t)` is called to get the memory, but there is no way to pass any alignment info to that allocation function (it just takes a size, nothing else!), so there is no way for that function to take the type's alignment into account, and it can only guarantee a hard-coded maximal alignment.

Comment: That's not a bug, it's by design of the C++ Standard. The compiler issue here is not a bug, it's a feature, and one G++ has no obligation to implement.

Comment: @Puppy Any item in a bug tracker is commonly referred to as a bug, regardless of whether it is by design. It's in that sense that I was using the term.

Comment: Then whoever is doing the referring (in this case you) is incorrect.

Comment: @Puppy That's not something I'm willing to get into a discussion about right now, as it is not relevant here. I've clarified what I meant. If my wording has flaws that make me hard to understand, I'll clarify. If my wording has flaws that don't make me hard to understand, I'm okay with that right now.

Comment: Related: there's an item on the [EWG issues list](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#4) with a link to a proposal for a change that would allow passing the required alignment to `operator new`, which if implemented by compilers could allow allocations such as those in the question to work, but it has not been accepted in its current form.

Comment: @hvd Should I make this answer a community wiki? It seems incomplete.

Comment: @Columbo If you feel the comments are worth incorporating into your answer, feel free to do so, but based on the current standard, I think you can consider your answer complete as it is.